# Batch save AI/PSD/INDD with PDF aswell in each application respectively, how?

Tags: pdf

This is probably asked already, but I couldn't find a sufficient answer, so hopefully you guys can!

When creating things such as corporate identities, I always save both the workfile (PSD/AI/INDD) and a PDF version aswell, for others to view.

However, having to click to save to both extensions for each file and each revision is quite time consuming and I was hoping there was a plugin or a short way to save both a workfile and a PDF version simultaneously.

Who can satisfy me with a glorious answer to fullfill this action? :)

Thank you!

edit: A solution with by just clicking 'save' which saves to preconfigured settings (file name excluded) would be the best, however, two prompted messages (the settings window for saving AI/PSD/INDD and the PDF settings window afterwards) directly after each other is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1):

Batching actions on a folder or directory is a way to take a group of files and perform a set of actions on those files, such as saving a version to pdf.

What it seems like though is that you are asking for a convenience method for each individual file when you are completely done and are about to save.

In each of these respective programs you would need to access the **Actions panel** via Windows -> Actions. You can then record an action that would mimic the process you would go through when saving your file to both file types, (AI/PSD/INDD and pdf). When it comes time to save your final output, you could then play this action and it would both save your file and export your file as a pdf.

[image: Action Panel]

A really helpful option when creating an action is that you can create a function key that essentially allows you to make a shortcut for that action. I usually map it to something like (CMD/CTRL + Shift + F11) for easy access that shouldn't interfere with any other shortcuts you have.

[image: Function Key]

As was mentioned in the comments, how you filename has important implications in actions. If you change the filename in the action you are making it so that every time you apply that action you are changing the filename. So don't change the filename when recording the action.

Comment: I've thought of such idea, yet never tried. However Im pessimistic about one thing, which could be wrong though:

If you record actions, such as in your screen shot, clicking the save button, choosing sizes, etc.. 

But what about the file name? 
Either though, I can imagine if you set the name when creating the file at start, you don't have to worry about the file naming at the saving moment, with the recording..

Could you please clarify, deny or confirm that? 

Thanks!

Comment: That's a really good question. I think it is safer to always save a copy when it comes to actions as to avoid any overwriting. How you name your filenames are important though! I will add it to my answer.

Comment: And what just came to mind: What about the prompt message "A file named 'x.ai' already exists. Do you want to overwrite this file?"

Two solutions are possible: The one you declare -> Save as copy, and second: Create a second action with one click extra, which is 'click 'yes' on the 'do you want to overwrite' prompt?'.

Or do you have a better idea? :)

Edit: And before I'm creating an action: Is it time based? Since saving sometimes takes longer than other files, especially with embedded images or multiple artboards..

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe actions doesn't care about that, it just overwrites without a prompt. So that's why it is safe to save a copy because it will add  'x copy.ai' which makes it unlikely that you will overwrite

Comment: I've just recorded the actions, tried it with some files and I noticed the file path is also saved.

So if I use the action, the files are saved to the location that was used when saving while recording.. While I didnt specify a location, however.

What I did was:
Record new action
- File/Save as -> Save as PDF -> click 'save'
- File/save as -> Save as AI -> Click 'save'
Stop recording

however, it shows up as
Recording
- Save as
....../users/x/Dropbox/folder/file
- Save as
....../users/x/dropbox/folder/file


And I can't seem to find a way to remove the specified location from the record..

Comment: To extend my comment: I found that you can turn on/off to show (saving) dialogs, however: I don't want to specify the location everytime, especially when because of the 'saved location', I need to specify the correct folder again. By having to choose the folder almost everytime, clicking save as, twice, manually, seems even easiar ..